# command prompt that accepts a specific value and using two functions in one onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I'm having problem in my if statement.. I'm doing a Jeopardy game and i want to ask the player to input a specific answer which does not work on my if statement bellow:

```
   function ques1() {
    var ans1 = prompt("What Does HTML stands for?");
    if (ans1 = "Hypertext Markup Language") {
        document.getElementById("quest1").innerHTML =
        "Your Answer is Correct!"
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById("quest1").innerHTML =
        "Your Answer is Wrong! The Correct Answer is Hypertext Markup Language"
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<button type="button" id="buttonID" value="Button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="ques1()">100</button>
</div>
```

I also want to implement this hide function to hide button after click but i cant seem to make it work even if i add semicolon ";" after first function on onclick part like onclick ="quick1(); hide()"

```
function hide() {
    if (document.getElementById)
        document.getElementById("buttonID").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

Comment: Your code is working without any issues!!! https://jsfiddle.net/bhxLee85/ (I made it `==` and tried with just `=` also!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
if (ans1 = "Hypertext Markup Language")
```

to this:

```
if (ans1 == "Hypertext Markup Language")
```

Also, it is a good practice to always and your lines with a semi-colon, even if the program runs with out them. i.e. change this:

```
document.getElementById("quest1").innerHTML =
    "Your Answer is Correct!"
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("quest1").innerHTML = "Your Answer is Correct!";
```

Comment: thanks hips!... but i want to know if you know how to add two functions for on onlclick? so buttons funtion will be asking a question and at the sametime hiding the button

Comment: You can use semicolons: `<button onclick="ques1();hide();"></button>`

Comment: i actually did that but it only calls the first function.. and just to make sure the hide(); function is working i removed the quest(); function and it did

Comment: You may want to try putting `hide()` first. i.e. `<button onclick="hide();ques1();"></button>`. If you can't get that to work, call `hide()` on the first line of the function `ques1()`.